# App hosted by OpenShift stops responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

So I've coded a pretty simple Telegram bot and [hosted it via OpenShift](http://diceogram-byshooterandy.rhcloud.com/). I am aware that applications can [go idle](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-idling.html) if not used for 24 hours, and it did happen before, but now this doesn't even seem to be the case: when I connect to it via `rhc ssh`, it doesn't show the usual warning about the app idling, and it doesn't start responding until I manually restart the gear. Not to mention that I did upgrade to Bronze, which should remove the idling altogether.

The issue manifests thusly: the bot stops responding to any commands, and, if I was connected to the shell and was "tailing" the node.js log (via `tail -f -n 100 app-root/logs/nodejs.log` or `rhc tail`), it shows no activity either (I have it log the received messages).

Is there a good way to see what causes it (since I'm rather new to this it could be a mistake on my part, or a mistake in the code of one of the requirements)?

Or, perhaps, is there at least a way to restart the gear through its index page, so that other people can kick it back to life?

Comment: You may want to check whether your gear is not [having memory issues](https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues).

Comment: @JiriFiala, yes, I did try that as well. Both return 0 even when the app is not responding.

I've also tried pretty much all the commands from the [resource mointoring](https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_am_i_getting_a_resource_temporarily_unavailable_error_when_using_rhc) section. Not all of them make sense to me, but here are the results anyway: http://orig05.deviantart.net/5ba6/f/2016/046/b/5/2016_02_16_00h13_57_by_shooter__andy-d9rvbyu.png
http://orig10.deviantart.net/d3ba/f/2016/046/f/8/2016_02_16_00h14_19_by_shooter__andy-d9rvbzc.png
(unsure if needed blur)

Comment: From the description it seems like the Telegram bot coud be consuming all available resources over time. Maybe [this monitoring cartridge](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-monit) will help you analyze this. Another option could be to keep the gear in the non-responsive state and contact OpenShift support for help.

Comment: @JiriFiala, nope, this doesn't seem to be the case. I've snapped the screenshot of the status page when it was not responding:
http://orig01.deviantart.net/1f78/f/2016/055/1/3/2016_02_24_22h23_23_by_shooter__andy-d9sy0q2.png
And, of course, there was no emails sent to me by the monitoring cartridge.